# Manipulating data within an object

Tags: php, laravel-5

Hi I am new to Laravel and php. In my database each student has three marks on each subject and I need to retrieve them and send to the view the average mark for each student.
I tried doing it like below, but the returned value is an object (e.g. [5,4,3]) and it doesn't let me count the average. Please advise how I can operate with data within the object.

```
$students = Student::all();

foreach ($students as $student) {
    $mathPoints = Point:: where('subject_id', 1)
        ->where('student_id', $student->id)
        ->pluck('points');
}
```

I tried turning it into an array by (array) method, but I couldn't calculate the sum of values with array_sum after.

Update: my Point model:

```
namespace App\Models;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Point extends Model
{
    //Get the student the credit points are related to
    public function student()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('App/Models/Student');
    }
    //Get the subject the credit points are related to
    public function subject()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('App/Models/Subject');
    }
}
```

Comment: can you please post your Point model?

Comment: @LiMi add that to the question

Comment: @YashKaranke added

Comment: Probably not part of the solution, but you have an errant space in `Point:: where`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use `Model::avg('columnName')` to calculate average .

read more here : https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/queries#aggregates

```
$students = Student::all();
foreach ($students as $student){
   $mathPoints = Point::where(['subject_id'=>1,'student_id'=>$student->id])->avg('points');
   $student->avgPoint=$mathPoints;
}
```

inside your blade :

```
{{ $student->avgPoint}}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
Point::where('student_id', $student->id)->get()
```

When you use `all()` with Eloquent, it makes the query for you. If you use `where()`, you have to ‘get’ it using `get()` before you can use it as a collection.

```
$mathPoints = Point::where('student_id', $student->id)
    ->get()
    ->pluck('points');
```

However, I’d probably look at using more complicated queries to fetch this data, as you could easily end up making hundreds of queries per page, rather than just 1.